# ubuntu 12.10 usb startup brought settings from the last computer

Tags: installation, settings

I used a usb to put 12.10 on a dell laptop. Everything is working fine. I used the same usb to put it on a dell desktop. Ubuntu is not working well on the desktop and in settings, claims to be the laptop (system settings). I would like to know how to make it reset. I think that it has graphics settings it picked up from the laptop installation. What should I do?

Comment: What was the source of the "usb"?  If it was an installation iso image of ubuntu, it should have been fine and not know anything about your other computer until it looked at it during the install.If you made a copy of an existing system to the usb, that would bring all its baggage with it.  This might also occur if you booted your original computer from the usb and just ran it from there.  The usb might then have saved settings from that.

Answer (score 1):

A persistent live usb will retain settings from your install. If you are not sure how to change the settings to what you need, the simplest thing would be to remake the usb, being sure to reformat the drive at the same time.